# wso2is in distributed architecture

Tags: wso2, system, distributed

i am a beginner in wso2 and working on a academic project that consists of deploying wso2 in a distributed architecture. I've been looking in wso2 documentation but I couldn't find something that can help me in this project. if u have any clue, that would be very helpful.

Comment: There's literally not even a question in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not clearly get what you requirement is. However you can create a distributed deployment of WSO2 APIM as  in [1].

There is no specific distributed deployment scenario of wso2 IS. However IS can be used in clustering as in previous answer.

Other than that, WSO2 products can be deployed by clustering. Refer this [2] such clustering patterns.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Distributed+Deployment+of+API+Manager

Answer (score 0):

You can find the clustering documentation for WSO2 IS 5.4.0 in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1